# CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() inserindo zerado

Tags: mysql, data

Estou inserindo mais de 9000 registros via query, mas o CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() -3 está inserindo vários campos com 0000-00-00 00:00:00.
Tem alguma forma de evitar isso?

```
INSERT INTO yourls.yourls_url (keyword, url, title, timestamp, ip, clicks) VALUES
('teste', 'meusite.com/teste.htm';, 'Testando o encurtador', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() -3, '198.xx.xxx.xxx', '');
```

Comment: Pode colocar o código do insert?

Comment: INSERT INTO `yourls`.`yourls_url` (`keyword`, `url`, `title`, `timestamp`, `ip`, `clicks`) VALUES ('teste', 'http://www.meusite.com/teste.htm', 'Testando o encurtador', CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() -3, '198.xx.xxx.xxx', '');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No INSERT é necessário evidenciar o que significa esse `-3` para você pode ser menos 3 horas(horario de Brasília) mas o mysql não sabe se são 3 horas, dias, meses, anos etc use a função [subdate](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_subdate) para diminuir 3 horas da data atual. [current_timestamp](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp) é sinônimo de now().

```
INSERT INTO yourls.yourls_url (keyword, url, title, timestamp, ip, clicks)
VALUES
('teste', 'meusite.com/teste.htm', 'Testando o encurtador', SUBDATE(now(), INTERVAL 3 hour), '198.xx.xxx.xxx', '');
```

[Exemplo - sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/3820), compare o resultado das duas últimas consultas elas dão 3 segundos de diferença ou seja é necessário especificar que são horas como feito na primera consulta.

Answer (score -3):

Para os que tem dificuldade de mudar o TimeZone do Banco de Dados MYSQL padrão +00:00 (bloqueador pelo Servidor de Hospedagem para alteração)

Segue umma solução de Criação de um **gatilho Trigger**. **Antes da Inserção - BEFORE **, para definir o valor para 'dtini' como -3 horas (horário de Brasilia/Brasil);

```
SET NEW.dtini = SUBDATE(now(), INTERVAL 3 hour)
```

[Clique para ver  Mysql Gatilho Exemplo Alterar TImezone Antes Insert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uscf3.png)

Comment: Isso acaba sendo gambiarrra (sem ofensa, é apenas no sentido de alertar contundentemente). Você pode configurar o timezone na própria conexão, tanto globalmente quanto individualmente (`SET time_zone`), é uma coisa bem básica e descrita na documentação. Não precisa ter acesso à configuração do banco e nenhuma permissão especial. Até seria absurdo se não tivesse isso, imagine uma aplicação que rode em várias regiões e timezones diferentes. Mesmo se não tivesse, seria o caso de armazenar tudo em UTC (de certa forma o My faz isso já) e gerenciar na aplicação para evitar efeitos colaterais.

Comment: Segue demonstração https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/baG7GqxME3ruHLJb9xANbA/0

Comment: Explicando a parte do porque é uma gambiarra. Toda vez que cria um trigger você embute uma sobrecarga de processamento nas operações atingidas pelo gatilho. Como @Bacco   demonstrou a configuração de zonas temporais é algo simples não tendo o porque de forçar uma sobrecarga de processamento sobre uma atividade simples.

Comment: E se um dia o horário de verão voltar, se lascou de novo, pois aí a diferença do Horário de Brasília com relação a UTC passa a ser de 2 horas (e aí vc vai ficar mudando de -3 pra -2, depois de volta pra -3, etc?) - Gerenciar isso manualmente nunca é a melhor opção. Uma opção menos pior seria usar `SET time_zone` com os nomes dos timezones (como `America/Sao_Paulo`, por exemplo), pois aí pelo menos ele trata as transições de horário de verão automaticamente. Ou simplesmente guardar tudo em UTC e só converter na hora de mostrar. Ver mais [aqui](/q/411035/112052) e [aqui](/q/371031/112052)

Comment: @hkotsubo _"e aí vc vai ficar mudando de -3 pra -2, depois de volta pra -3, etc?"_ bem lembrado. Até porque, imagine como vão ficar os dados já inseridos misturados com os novos. Fora que, independente do horário de verão, nosso território não é só -03:00, temos mais fusos.